# Can features not related to Q&A be disabled?

Tags: support

I am not a developer, I will never be a developer. I am not interested in teams, job ads, stories, or comparing salaries. I would simply like to use SO as a place to find answers to my questions or answer questions myself. Is it possible to hide the "noise"?

Comment: Probaly not natively but you can do a lot with Stylish and Scripting - https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox

Comment: Someone probably has a userscript or can tell you what divs/CSS to hide in something like Adblock Pro, but there isn't a site feature to do this.

Comment: Job ads are ads. Companies generally don't want you to disable those, even if it's not relevant to you specifically. If I could just disable all the ads I'm not interested in on the site itself, I wouldn't need Adblock. Although there may be some merit in showing *different* ads for non-developers (but then what if someone becomes a developer who previously didn't think they would?).

Comment: possibly related: [Can we show new/anonymous users more Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314134/165773) at MSE (as a side note, chances to get what you ask for are [near zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/165773))

Comment: adblock pretty easily gets rid of all the noise, and there's no adblock blocker scripts here.

Comment: I've posted a userscript at https://stackapps.com/q/8032/

Comment: @astonearachnid Consider posting as an answer?

Comment: Wow. A question that fits both on meta and the main site. :D

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but if you're not a developer, what's your interest in Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Flimm, as I said "I would simply like to use SO as a place to find answers to my questions or answer questions myself."

Comment: @Flimm I am a scientist using R for statistical analysis and data visualisation. See my questions and answers for examples...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My userscript at https://stackapps.com/q/8032 hides Teams, Jobs, the Salary Calculator and Developer Stories from the interface, so you can focus on Q&A.

([Download](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Userscripts/raw/master/hide-teams-and-jobs.user.js) from GitHub, [more info](https://stackapps.com/q/8032) on Stack Apps)